# handle middleware through function is it possible

Tags: node.js, express

i have few confusion let me show code first

in  app.js

```
 app.oauth=require('./serverice/login') // this is 1 middleware
 app.islogin=require('./middleware/islogin')(app)  // this is 2 middleware
 app.get('/next', app.islogin,(req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard/dashboard');
 });
```

and in middleware islogin.js

```
     function IsLogin(appauth){
      //get req.token from 1 middleware and do somecondition
    }
    module.exports=IsLogin
```

my first middleware next give like req.token now my confusing is that can i handle this req.token in second middleware is it possible or not is there any other good way

Comment: you can return the `req.token` as a promise, making the return variable as global and using reject and resolve on null or not null value , make use that promise in second middleware

Comment: @P.hunter is there any way to get value of next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a middleware inside `IsLogin` function.

```
  // login.js
  function login(req, res, next){
       res.locals.valueToPass = value;
  }

  // isLogin.js
  function IsLogin(appauth){
  //get req.token from 1 middleware and do somecondition
      return function (req, res, next){
          let value = res.locals.valueToPass;
       }

  }
  module.exports=IsLogin
```

Comment: my problem is not return.  is that how i can access appauth next value

Comment: Are you trying to pass some value in `next` parameter from your oauth middleware?

Comment: yes basically oauth give some value in his next which i want to recieve at 2 middleware

Comment: Technically , that is not possible. You can append the values to want to pass in response object. Recommended is using `res.locals`. Then get the value back in the other middlewares from response object.